# Relationship between UIBezierPath point coordinate system and the layer's

Tags: core-animation, calayer, uibezierpath

I am really confused by `UIBezierPath`'s point system and its corresponding function such as `moveToPoint`.

Which coordinate system does the point belong to? It doesn't even have a layer until we assign it to some layer's `path`.

For example, we have a new `UIBezierPath` that add a line from `50, 0` to `100, 0`. But what does `50` and `100` represent here? Does it mean a position in terms of the layer's bound?

Comment: `UIBezierPath` coordinates use `CGPoint` ... if you're setting the `.path` property of a `CAShapeLayer` it is relative to the upper-left corner (0,0) of that layer. If that's not clear, or if it's not giving you the results you expect, then you need to edit your question with a concrete example of what you're trying to do.

Comment: @DonMag Thanks Don! That's exactly what I am asking